# Sphinx: customize sidebar section titles

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sidebar, tableofcontents

I am documenting my Python project with Sphinx. As some of my documentation pages are rather long, I would like to have both a local and a global table of contents in the sidebar. I achieve achieve this via

```
html_sidebars = { '**': ['localtoc.html', 'globaltoc.html', 'searchbox.html'] }
```

The result is almost as desired. However, both the local and the global table of contents have the same title ("Table of Contents"). That is, it looks like

```
Table of Contents
 - Subheading 1
 - Subheading 2
 - Subheading 3

Table of Contents
 - Subpage 1
 - Subpage 2
 - Subpage 3
```

This is confusing to the reader.

I have located the file `localtoc.html` in the sphinx package folder of my Python installation, and adjusting the html to my needs (replacing the title) is simple. However, I would not like to change a Sphinx source file, and building my own theme via a python package seems overkill to me.

Is there any way to replace  `localtoc.html` locally, i.e. for the current project only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the behaviour of the `localtoc.html` template.

Create a `_templates` folder in your Sphinx root (the same place where your `conf.py` file is located), and copy `localtoc.html` from your Sphinx installation to this folder.

You can then modify this file as you wish. Remove this line:

```
<h3><a href="{{ pathto(master_doc) }}">{{ _('Table of Contents') }}</a></h3>
```

to get rid of the extra heading, or you could replace any of the text, as you wish (for example changing the content of the `<a>` to `Local Contents` or whatever you like.

Note that changing the `localtoc.html` removes the **top** of the two headings. If this is what you wanted, great! If not, you could replicate the process just using `globaltoc.html` in the same way.